# kUbuntu 22.04 ssd slow boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kubuntu, ssd, 22.04

I'm already clean `/tmp/*` and add `TimeoutStartSec=10sec` to `NetworkManager.service`, but boot still slow:

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 40.754s
└─multi-user.target @1min 40.754s
  └─srv1cv83.service @1min 35.451s +5.302s
    └─network-online.target @1min 35.427s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1min 30.542s +4.884s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1min 30.497s +42ms
          └─network-pre.target @1min 30.496s
            └─windscribe-helper.service @1min 30.496s
              └─basic.target @1min 30.473s
                └─sockets.target @1min 30.473s
                  └─libvirtd-ro.socket @1min 30.473s
                    └─libvirtd.socket @1min 30.471s +1ms
                      └─sysinit.target @1min 30.468s
                        └─systemd-timesyncd.service @1min 30.343s +124ms
                          └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @1min 30.328s +13ms
                            └─local-fs.target @1min 30.319s
                              └─run-docker-netns-1d0e918af1c8.mount @1min 37.051s
                                └─local-fs-pre.target @308ms
                                  └─lvm2-monitor.service @191ms +116ms
                                    └─systemd-journald.socket @186ms
                                      └─system.slice @153ms
                                        └─-.slice @153ms
```

[image]

Comment: `run-docker-netns-1d0e918af1c8.mount @1min 37.051s` - seems to be the main "culprit"

Comment: @Hannu so what I should to do? Disable docker autorun somehow?

Comment: Whether that is an option is up to you. You have to consider how much use *you* have of docker. Further; *I* have no idea how quick startups docker might be capable of, actually.